# How to centre single bar position with multiple bars in position_dodge in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have the following geom_bar dodged plot and think the single bars for Ages 8, 17, 26 and 27 would look better centralized rather than off to the left. I am not sure what to add to the script to achieve this. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

This is the script:

```
ggplot(data = combo1, aes(x = Age_Year, fill = Tactic)) + 
    geom_bar(position = position_dodge(preserve = 'single')) + 
    theme_classic() + 
    labs(x = "Age (years)", y = "Counts of Fish", show.legend = FALSE)+
    theme(legend.position = "none")+
    scale_fill_manual("legend",  values = c("Migr" = "skyblue", "OcRes" = "pale green", "EstRes" = "pink"))
```

Comment: Please make the question reproducible; add the output of `dput(combo1)` to the question; see [MRE].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP, use `position_dodge2(preserve="single")` in place of `position_dodge(preserve="single")`.  For some reason, centering bars/columns doesn't quite work correctly with `position_dodge()`, but it does with `position_dodge2()`.  Note the slight difference in spacing you get when you switch the position function, but should overall be the fix to your problem.

##### Reproducible Example for OP's question

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(8675309)
df <- data.frame(
  x=c("A", "A", "A", "B", "C", "C"),
  grouping_var = c("Left", "Middle", "Right", "Middle", "Left", "Right"),
  values = sample(1:100, 6))
```

Basic plot with `position_dodge()`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=values, fill=grouping_var)) +
  geom_col(position=position_dodge(preserve = "single")) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

When you use `position_dodge2()`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=values, fill=grouping_var)) +
    geom_col(position=position_dodge2(preserve = "single")) +
    theme_classic()
```

[image]